# Vertical lines disappear from table when using commands

Tags: tables, macros

I am trying to create a table which includes information define via `\newcommand` elsewhere in my document.  When I use the command sequence I created the vertical lines between the cells in my table disappear.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\newcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{Template}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 A & \shorttitle & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 A & Template & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

and this is how the tables come out:
[image: tableimage]

I want it to appear as in the second example but without explicitly typing the text as I want to input the same text at several points in my document.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

BTW In my actual document the table appears in a footer which is defined in a separate .sty file so I need to define the command in one file and use it in another

Comment: `\shorttitle` has an argument and you're using it without, so it gobbles the `&` next to it

Comment: Welcome! `\shorttitle` requires an argument, but you don't provide any. Either define it without, like `\newcommand\shorttitle{Template}` (omit `[1]`), or add an empty argument in the table, `\shorttitle{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Either use `\shorttitle{}` or remove the `[1]` in the definition of `\newcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{Template}`, otherwise `\shorttitle` expects an argument and the first thing it finds is the `&`, being gobbled to nirvana (;-)), so this will remove a table column (in display)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\newcommand{\shorttitle}[1]{Template}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 A & \shorttitle{} & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}% Really?

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 A & Template & B & C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]